# How to make listView say one thing, but pass through different data

Tags: java, android, listview

So this question is a little hard to explain, but basically what i want is to have an array list for a listview, but change the title on the listview. So that when the user sees the listview it says one thing, but passes through different information.
Here's my code:

```
//the string names
String names[] = { "item1", "item2"};
```

i have 2 classes called item1.java and item2.java
when one listitem is clicked it sets a class equal to the activity name and opens it like this:

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    String openClass = names[position];
    try{
        Class selected = Class.forName("com.example.example." + openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

But in the listview i don't want it to say "item1" and "item2"....is there any way to make like an alias or something? 
Sorry if my question is hard to understand i tried my best to explain what i need help with let me know if you have any questions about my question(: thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this the same way you make any custom adapter, such as one that should display images instead of or in addition to some text.

For example, if your adapter is an `ArrayAdapter`, you create a subclass, override `getView()`, and do what you want in there to format your rows the way that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `toString()` to do this. See following example

```
public static class Alias {
    String originalValue;
    public Alias(String s) {
        this.originalValue = s;
    } 

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "What are you want to show";
    }
}

String names[] = {"item1", "item2"};
Alias array[] = new Alias[names.length];
Alias array[0] = new Alias(names[0]);
Alias array[1] = new Alias(names[1]);
ArrayAdapter<Alias> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Alias>(this, resId, array);
```

This will show "What are you want to show" in every listview whatever the value is.